# Showing ControlBox When Mdi Child Form is Maximized

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, windows-forms-designer

When I click maximize in control box on child form, control box buttons are disappearing. How can I prevent that? I want to show that control box part like when I do  this :

```
"Form1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill"
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [XtraForm.AllowMdiBar](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.AllowMdiBar) property that control whether an MDI bar is allowed for this form:
[image: MdiBar]

P.S. This property is in effect for a parent MDI form, when the title bar skinning feature is enabled.
P.P.S. See also the [Remarks](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.AllowMdiBar#remarks) section.

Comment: Yes it works but I do this in ToolbarForm. I have a bar with buttons on the top. When I maximize child form, the MDI bar is going over the bar with buttons. Can MDI bar stay below the top bar?